# Live search box with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using bootstrap I create one accordion `panel-group` that is populated with several `panel-default` and want to add a live search box to show only the panels that the user needs.

I found some examples of how to do that but with `<nav>`, `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, I tried to do it with the `<div>` tags but I can't make it work.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to show us how you did that? and help you

Comment: Actually I use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/umaar/t82gZ/ but I don't know how use the `<div>` tag and the different classes I use like `panel-group`, `panel-heading`, `panel-body`, `panel-default`, etc.

Comment: Ok, i see, but can you make a fiddle with a little part of your code? maybe just one div or two. I know how to do that and i juts want to help you better

Comment: Here's an example
https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/yarn8kw2/

Comment: Thank you so much Gerardo, this Works good, now i just need clean my code.

Comment: You're welcome, anything else related just comment and i'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you request

with the fiddle you are using just change the loop selector

for this `$("#panel, .panel-group, .panel-heading, .panel-body, .panel-default")`

You can iterate through the classes what you want adding a `.` and the name of the class, `#` and name of the id for id's and if is there more than one just separate it by comma. The `.each()` is gonna search into all that elements and search you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/yarn8kw2/1/